# Not able to share link using Sharekit in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

I am using the sharekit to use facebook

Now here..

I want to "share link" in the facebook for this I have found this way in the sharekit documentation

```
  // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

// Share the item
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

But I dont know this is not working..I am able to see opened facebook page but this link is not being shared in my Facebook page.

Can anyone tell me the solution??

Comment: Please share complete method of sharing a URL, as I m new to Sharekit and do not know ho to share a link....

Comment: @AsifHabib ... use above code and do changes in configuration file as stated in sharkit website

Comment: #define SHKFacebookKey              @""
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""

Comment: write above code and then code of the question @AsifHabib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you change the configuration file?

You need to set the correct key and secrets in the configuration.

Comment: ohh ...I was just making the dummy project so I was not aware of that...thanks I'll do that..new bie..:( here

Comment: Do u know any tutorial or any example which can help me with this?

Comment: Check the documentation on the sharekit website. http://www.getsharekit.com/install/

Comment: Please share complete method of sharing a URL, as I m new to Sharekit and do not know ho to share a link....

Comment: @AsifHabib its a bit rude to just ask for code, thus I shall not give you anything except some advise: Read the share documentation.

Comment: @rckoenes: I agree and tried a lot to run sharekit, I m trying to post a link ask.com and title: ABC, Currenlty I m making a sample projected with one page and one button ShareFacebook. cliking on that button will share link and title on my behalf. but do not know how to login, keep login details. I want to know the details and steps to share link on facebook, could not find on google, tell the steps or suggest a link... Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to fill these details in SHKConfig.h file

```
#define SHKFacebookKey              @""
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""
```